sudo apt update не работает
когда ввожу sudo apt update: выводит ошибку
Hit:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease                          
Get:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease [3638 B]
Hit:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Fetched 3638 B in 1s (2757 B/s)
E: LZ4F: /var/lib/apt/lists/http.kali.org_kali_dists_kali-rolling_contrib_Contents-amd64.lz4 Unexpected end of file
E: LZ4F: /var/lib/apt/lists/http.kali.org_kali_dists_kali-rolling_contrib_Contents-amd64.lz4 Read error (18446744073709551615: ERROR_GENERIC)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 32, in <module>
    col.create(db)
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 96, in create
    self._fill_commands(con)
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 145, in _fill_commands
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(returncode=sub.returncode,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/lib/apt/apt-helper cat-file /var/lib/apt/lists/http.kali.org_kali_dists_kali-rolling_contrib_Contents-amd64.lz4' returned non-zero exit status 100.
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code

попробовал сделать действия из этого вопроса ничего не изменилось.
у меня стоит Operating System: Kali GNU/Linux Rolling, Kernel: Linux 6.6.15-amd64.

вопрос больше не актуален. я не нашёл адекватного решения и переустановил линукс.
